# Unable to use mex on R2010a

Tags: visual-studio-2010, matlab, mex

I'm using Matlab R2010a. I need to create a custom block embedded with my code for which i require mex. I have Visual Studio Express 2010 installed on my system. I followed the instructions and installed the mex patch for R2010a into the matlabroot folder using the unzip command. I also installed Windows SDK 7.1 64 bit as recommended. However when i type        mex -setup no compiler is shown. Any alternative solutions?

Comment: If you pay for your Matlab installation, make sure you ask their Tech Support this question.

Answer (score 0):

Is your matlab 64Bits? I don't think it supports mex (or there is some problems. I don't remember). I had this problem and switched to a newer version.